# How to get Object Id of Azure Resource using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

How can I get the Object Id of an Azure resource using PowerShell cmdlets?

I tried using `Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName 'my-resource' | fl` but it fails with error: `Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters`

I also tried using `Get-AzResource -Name 'my-resource'` but among the information it retrieves it doesn't include the Object Id.

Comment: It seems this is a known bug [Hyphens are not interpreted as they are on the portal page for Get-AzureRmResource](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6985)
However, according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.1.0) example 4, you should be able to get the Id by using 
`(Get-AzResource -Name 'my-resource').ResourceId`

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, there is no such `Object Id` for azure resources in the subscription, there is just a `ResourceId` with the format `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/{resource-provider-namespace}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}`.

You can get it via `Get-AzResource` you used, it returns the `ResourceId`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late but you could try something like

```
$Id = (Get-AzResource -Name 'my-resource' -ResourceType {resource-type}).Identity.PrincipalId
```

Link here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44391